# How to make calculator calculate in decimal form

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

Here's my code for my calculator and it works fine!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var number1 = 0
var number2 = 0
var operation = 0

@IBOutlet var screen: UILabel!


@IBAction func Onebutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(1)
}

@IBAction func Twobutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(2)
}

@IBAction func Threebutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(3)
}

@IBAction func Fourbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(4)
}

@IBAction func Fivebutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(5)
}

@IBAction func Sixbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(6)
}

@IBAction func Sevenbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(7)
}

@IBAction func Eightbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(8)
}

@IBAction func Ninebutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(9)
}

@IBAction func Zerobutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    addNumber(0)
}

@IBAction func Multiplybutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    operation = 1
}

@IBAction func Dividebutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    operation = 2
}

@IBAction func Addbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    operation = 3
}

@IBAction func Subtractbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    operation = 4
}

@IBAction func Equalsbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    switch operation{
    case 1: screen.text = String (number1*number2)
    case 2: screen.text = String (number1/number2)
    case 3: screen.text = String (number1+number2)
    case 4: screen.text = String (number1-number2)
    default: println()
    }
}


@IBAction func clearbutton(sender: AnyObject) {
    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0
    operation = 0
    screen.text = "0"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func addNumber (pushButton : Int){
    if operation == 0 {
        number1 = number1*10+pushButton
        screen.text = String (number1)
    } else {
        number2 = number2*10+pushButton
        screen.text = String (number2)
    }
}

}
```

But I want to make the calculator calculate in decimal form and not round off to the nearest number.

Answer (score 2):

Use floats.

```
var number: Float = 0
number = number + 0.1
println(number)
//0.1 should be printed.
```

You are currently basically saying:

```
var number: Int = 0
```

This is pretty much how the computer reads it; number is an integer. To make it so that number can be a decimal (float), you have to say:

```
var number: Float = 0
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response, I replaced all the ints to floats but there is an error in Equalsbutton function and the addnumber function (these are in the above coding in question). What is going wrong? One of the errors is that Float is not convertible to UInt8.

Comment: you say that var operation = 0, so nothing should happen according to your switch statement. Also, I am fairly sure that you are using incorrect format. Take a look at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html to see how to do a switch statement correctly. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi this is urgent and I don't have time to look at all the websites. Could you please fix the code for me and explain the errors. But I do understand what u are trying to say. Thank you for your response and your patience. I am a begginer.

Comment: never mind, i have fixed the code and it is working like i want it to!           Here's the code:

Comment: sorry about the comment above. dont worry about what i asked earlier. I have fixed and understood the code and it is working like i want it to!  Thank you for your help again. But every time i put a number in the display, it comes out with a decimal point behind the number and i am adding decimal point button on the calculator. How could I do that?